# Rails ActiveResource::Base or Redmine error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, ruby-on-rails-3.2, redmine, activeresource

I'm trying to user Redmine via REST API in order to keep and update Projects Membership, as explained in http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Rest_Memberships

In order to do so, I included, in my client application, written in RoR, the following 'redmine_project' model:

```
class RedmineProject < ActiveResource::Base
  self.site ='http://localhost:3001'
  self.format = :json
  self.user = 'admin'
  self.password = 'admin'
  self.element_name = 'project'
  self.collection_name = 'projects'

end
```

Then , in my console, I'm trying to include a new membership, with the following command:

```
RedmineProject.find(4).post(:memberships,:user_id => 12, :role_ids => [4])
```

The first part of the commend is properly treated by Redmine (actually, if I just try RedmineProject.find(4) I do get a JSON with my project data) but..
**I'm unable to Post the new membership** with

> .post(:memberships,:user_id => 12, :role_ids => [4])

Here is the result of my application console:

```
ActiveResource::ServerError: Failed.  Response code = 500.  Response message = Internal Server Error .
    from /home/marc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activeresource-3.2.13/lib/active_resource/connection.rb:148:in `handle_response'
```

and here is the result of the redmine terminal:

```
Started POST "/projects/4/memberships.json?role_ids%5B%5D=4&user_id=12" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-10-24 21:32:41 +0200
Processing by MembersController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"project"=>{"created_on"=>"2013-10-23T00:58:15Z", "description"=>"azfazfazf zaf azffza", "homepage"=>"", "id"=>4, "identifier"=>"team-35", "name"=>"azfazf", "updated_on"=>"2013-10-23T00:58:15Z"}, "role_ids"=>["4"], "user_id"=>"12", "project_id"=>"4"}
WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
   (0.6ms)  SELECT MAX(`settings`.`updated_on`) AS max_id FROM `settings` 
  User Load (0.9ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`type` IN ('User', 'AnonymousUser') AND `users`.`login` = 'admin'
  SQL (95.6ms)  UPDATE `users` SET `last_login_on` = '2013-10-24 21:32:41' WHERE `users`.`type` IN ('User', 'AnonymousUser') AND `users`.`id` = 1
  Current user: admin (id=1)
  Project Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `projects`.* FROM `projects` WHERE `projects`.`id` = 4 LIMIT 1
  EnabledModule Load (0.4ms)  SELECT name FROM `enabled_modules` WHERE `enabled_modules`.`project_id` = 4
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 127ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `valid?' for nil:NilClass):
  app/controllers/members_controller.rb:70:in `block (2 levels) in create'
  app/controllers/members_controller.rb:65:in `create'
```

**Is there something wrong with my code?** or is it a (unlikely) bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do assumption that you use Redmine v2.3

Looking at at the [place](https://github.com/redmine/redmine/blob/2.3-stable/app/controllers/members_controller.rb#L70) where error is raised I see that `members` is empty array!
Looking at the process of building `members` I can suppose that `params[:membership]` is blank, please see your log:

```
{"project"=>{"created_on"=>"2013-10-23T00:58:15Z", "description"=>"azfazfazf zaf azffza", "homepage"=>"", "id"=>4, "identifier"=>"team-35", "name"=>"azfazf", "updated_on"=>"2013-10-23T00:58:15Z"}, "role_ids"=>["4"], "user_id"=>"12", "project_id"=>"4"}
```

Try to change sending parameters to wrap them into `membership`.
Something like this described in the [document](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Rest_Memberships)

```
{
  "membership":
  {
    "user_id": 27,
    "role_ids": [ 2 ]
  }
}
```

I think this should work

```
.post(:memberships,:membership => {:user_id => 12, :role_ids => [4]})
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a Lot for your help @gotva , The only thing is that I needed to include, in the param :membership (without S), thus we have:


`.post(:memberships,:membership => {:user_id => 12, :role_ids => [4]}) `


Thanks a lot, I couldn't make it without you :)